# What does it mean that "Expression returns values" in programming?

Tags: javascript, operators, expression

What does "Operators return values" in programming?
I mean, take the + operator.
If we have 2 numbers (not strings)as operands, it sums the operands togheter. But what does it mean that it returns a value? Isn't is just supposed to sum two numbers togheter?

I really don't get what this "return" mean, the value is returned to...who/what/where?

Comment: To whatever the expression is applied to. `1 + 1` throws away the value. `const foo = 1 + 1` assigns the value to `foo`. You might be over-thinking this.

Comment: What do you get after summing the values, if it's not the return value of the operation?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't think your comment really addresses the question. Whether or not the line reads as `foo = 1 + 1` or just `1 + 1`, `1 + 1` will always return a value. Your really talking about whether or not to capture that returned value.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Perhaps. The questions asks "what is it returned to". It's returned to whatever context the expression is in.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I think Dave meant the statement `1 + 1;` which discards the value

Comment: @Bergi Yes, I got that, but it can be a little misleading to someone who is asking what a return value really is, because `1 + 1` will always return a value, whether you store the value or not.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Right, but I said `1 + 1` throws away that value, which it does. The return value is "returned" to nothing, because there's nothing there. The question was "what does expression returns values mean" or "the value is returned to what?", not "what is a return value".

Comment: @DaveNewton We are in agreement. I'm just trying to clarify the difference between returning a value and not returning a value vs. returning a value and not capturing a returned value.

Answer (score 1):

> the value is returned to...who/what/where?

To whatever did *evaluate* the expression, or put otherwise, whatever did want the interpreter to evaluate the expression. Just like a function returns a value to its caller, the interpreter returns the result of the evaluation. Don't overthink it.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it in terms of speaking. When you speak, you can make a statement, as in: "I'm hungry." This would not require a "response" from the other person in the conversation, but if I said "Are you hungry?", I would expect a response.

In other words sometimes the statements you write are just instructions to be followed that don't result in any "response" from the system, but others do and those responses are what we call the "return value" of the statement.

So, `1 + 1` is something that returns a value - - the system will carry out the command and a new value will be the result. That new value is the return value. Now, you need to know what kinds of statements do return values and which don't so you can decide if you want to capture that returned value and/or do something with it.

```
 1 + 1  // 2 will be returned from this, but the code doesn't capture it

 foo = 1 + 1  // Now the 2 will be returned and captured for future use by the program
```

But, `console.log("Hello")` is an instruction that will be carried out and no response (return value) will be generated. So, it wouldn't make any sense to write:

```
 foo = console.log("Hello");
```

Because nothing is returned from `console.log()`, so `foo` would wind up being `undefined` even though the message would still be written to the `console`.

In fact, if you aren't sure if a statement will or won't return a value, you can find out by trying to assign a variable to the result and then checking the variable:

```js
let foo = console.log("Hello");  // Hello
console.log(foo);                // undefined   


let bar = 1 + 1;
console.log(bar);  // 2
```

As you can see, when there is a return value, the statement that caused it is the statement that decides whether to capture it or not - - the return value is returned as a result of the statement. So, as discussed earlier in this answer, the statement `1+1` will cause the system to do the math and return the answer to the code context that spawned the action in the first place, but that statement isn't prepared to receive the response and so the response is never captured and, for all intents and purposes, is gone. But `foo = 1 + 1` is prepared for the return value by saying that `foo` should store or capture the return value from executing the statement `1+1`.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to say `console.log` "doesn't return a value", all JS functions return a value. It doesn't return a *useful* value, though, for sure 

Comment: @DaveNewton True! `undefined` is a value that means "nothing to see here, move along". ;)

Comment: OP is asking about expressions (as per the title and tags of the question), not about statements.